# Howto determine the size of a string give the current font in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is there a way to determine the display length of a given string (in pixels) based on the currently selected font in (C++) wxWidgets?

For example if I print out the string "Speed:" and want to put 10 pixels between the ':' and the value about to follow, I need to know how long the "Speed:" string was.  Is there a way to determine this?  I can't seem to find anything in the API documentation but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdc.html#wxdcgettextextent ?

Note: I'm not a wxWidgets user.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the one I needed.  For some reason I just missed it when looking over the documentation.