# How to calculate appropriate wxTextCtrl widget width for IP address entry?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am using wxTextCtrl to get IP address from user. Obviously, no IP v4 address may be longer than 15 characters, but the glyph size depends on environment (OS, user settings, etc), so I am a bit hesitant about setting some fixed size for the wxTextCtrl that I use.

What is the best way to calculate the control size in this case?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/241516/16582

Comment: Hm. Yes, I agree it is